# Chrome Omnibox Origin Chip

Tags: mac, google-chrome

Chrome's omnibox origin chip is become default every page, however,  it enabled when i hit the tab key in autocomplete in search pages before the last update. How can i change it to old version?

Comment: Er, did you try pressing ESC?

Comment: could you post your answer as an answer(we're not a forum after all, as per [help], and you can get upvoted for both)? And maybe add some screenshots to the question so its clearer what it is?

Comment: I tried to add screenshots when i open the topic but it says i need  least 5 reputation to add images.

Comment: Then upload your images at e.g https://imageshack.com/ and put the link into your post. Someone with enough rep will edit the question and copy the pics in.

Answer (score 0):

Disable omnibox chip in chrome://flags/.